# Finding probability mass function for Y= 2x+4

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm studying discrete random variables and pmf. Everything seems to make sense except when I need to find the pmf for random variables like this. I'm given the following information.

[image]

I understand for part (a), that the answer is 10 because the probabilities have to add up to one in that case. However, for part (b), I don't understand how they compute the pmf for the discrete variable, Y. Any help or approach would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What definition do you have for pmf?

Also start with finding where Y has a positive probability, since you know where X has a positive probability.

Comment: @Nate8 This is the one we were given in class "pX(x)=P(X=x) is the probability mass function (pmf) for the discrete random variable.  "  I just don't understand how you can use the P(X) from the random variable X to compute the pmf of the random variable Y.

Comment: You can now use that definition, the definition in the problem introduction, and the definition of Y (Y=2X+4), to find the pmf for Y

Comment: @Nate8 Thanks I think I understand! I basically plug in the values of x for the discrete variable Y, and I use the probabilities that I need to compute for pX(x) to calculate P(Y). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{align}
\because~p_X(x) ~=&~\mathsf P(X=x)\\[1ex] ~=&~ \begin{cases}\dfrac{x^2}{10} & : x\in\{-2,-1,1,2\}\\[1ex] 0 & : \textsf{elsewhere}\end{cases}
\\[2ex]
Y~=&~2X+4
\\[3ex]
\therefore~p_Y(y) ~=&~\mathsf P(Y=y)\\[1ex] ~=&~ \mathsf P\Big(X=\dfrac{y-4}{2}\Big) 
\\[1ex] ~=&~ \begin{cases}\textsf{what?} & : y\in\textsf{where?}\\[1ex] 0 & : \textsf{elsewhere}\end{cases}
\end{align}$

That is all.   Just fill in the missing details.   The what and where fore.

Comment: This is also a good way to explain it.

Comment: Is it the same as above, since I'm still using the random variable X, except now the numbers are where y is a member of the set {0,2,6,8}? Then I just simply plug those into y-4/2 then use the pmf x^2/10 to get the correct values?

Comment: @user2598152 Yes, that is the **where**.  The **what** involves substitution of $x\leftarrow\frac{y-4}{2}$ into the pmf.  As a reality check, you need $\mathsf P(Y=0)~=~\mathsf P(X=-2)~=~\tfrac 4{10}$ and so forth.  Make sure it does.